# C++ "No raw loops" without losing perfomance

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops

So the 'new (old) big thing' is "No Raw Loops" in C++. I'm trying to write code that way, but it seems very inefficient. Yes, there are STL algoritms which can do about anything, but they don't seem very efficient.

I for instance have a situation where I want a pointer to a node in an array of nodes that has the highest score. Determining that score is a costly floating-point operation. So I implemented the STL algorithm version and compared it with the raw loop:

```
#include <cfloat>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

static int counter;

class Node {
public:
    auto Score() const -> double {
        std::cout << "complex calculation\n";
        counter++;
        return 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    
    std::array<Node, 10> nodes;
    
    counter = 0;
    Node const* nodePtr = std::max_element(std::cbegin(nodes), std::cend(nodes),
        [](Node const& node1, Node const& node2) {
            return node1.Score() < node2.Score();
        });
    std::cout << "algorithm count " << counter << std::endl;
    
    counter = 0;
    double maxScore = -FLT_MAX;
    for (const auto& node : nodes) {
        auto score = node.Score();
        if (score > maxScore) {
            maxScore = score;
            nodePtr = &node;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "raw loop count " << counter << std::endl;
}
```

Evaluating this, for the STL version, the costly Score function is evaluated 18 times, while the raw loop only uses 10 evaluations...

Am I doing it wrong, or are raw loops just not that bad?

edit:
After the suggestion by `user58697` that cout and the static counter would prevent compiler optimization, I changed the code:

```
#include <cfloat>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

template <typename T>
class Random {
private:
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> distribution;
public:
    Random()
        : generator()
        , distribution(0.0, 1.0)
    {}

    auto operator()() {
        return distribution(generator);
    };
};

static Random<double> myRandom;

class Timer {
private:
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point startTime{};
public:
    void Start() noexcept {
        startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    [[nodiscard]] auto ElapsedMs() const noexcept {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime).count();
    }
};

static Timer timer;

class Node {
private:
    double val;
public:
    Node() noexcept : val(myRandom()) {}

    [[nodiscard]] auto Score() const noexcept {
        auto score = std::sqrt(std::log(10.0 / val));
        score = std::sin(score) / std::cos(score);
        score = std::sqrt(std::sqrt(std::sqrt(std::sqrt(std::sqrt(score)))));
        score = std::pow(score, 1000);
        return score;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::array<Node, 100000> nodes; // yeah, yeah... overloading the stack, I know

    for (auto i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        timer.Start();
        Node const* nodePtr = &*std::max_element(std::cbegin(nodes), std::cend(nodes),
            [](Node const& node1, Node const& node2) {
                return node1.Score() < node2.Score();
            });
        std::cout << "algorithm elapsed time " << timer.ElapsedMs() << std::endl;

        timer.Start();
        double maxScore = -FLT_MAX;
        for (const auto& node : nodes) {
            auto score = node.Score();
            if (score > maxScore) {
                maxScore = score;
                nodePtr = &node;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "raw loop count " << timer.ElapsedMs() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I run the loop twice to eliminate startup behavior... results of second loop (compiled with g++ 9.1 -O3):

```
algorithm elapsed time 16
raw loop count 8 (<== I see I forgot to change "count" to "time" :P)
```

So that's not it.

edit:
Seeing this question got an upvote, people are still looking at it.
Since this question was asked, C++20 was released. C++20's ranges library has a special feature which could have helped here, called [Projection](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/projections-with-ranges).

I.e. in this case you could use [`std::ranges::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/max_element) or even [`std::ranges::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/max) (which was missing from the old std algorithms) like

```cpp
Node const* node = &*std::ranges::max_element(nodes, {}, &Node::Score);
...
Node const& node = std::ranges::max(nodes, {}, &Node::Score);
```

However, projection is not the solution here, due to the implementation choice, which doesn't use caching. The `Proj` projection function is called again and again for *every* argument of the `Comp` comparator function.

(The internal function call looks something like

```cpp
return std::invoke(__comp, std::invoke(__proj, __a), std::invoke(__proj, __b)) ? __b : __a;
```

)

Comment: Regarding the use of the term STL : [What's the difference between “STL” and “C++ Standard Library”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library).

Comment: See also: [Should one prefer STL algorithms over hand-rolled loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135129/10077)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it's something [Sean Parent said in 2013](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning), but in recent CppCon many presenters quoted him on this.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It was advice Sean Parent gave back in at least 2013: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2tWOdzgXHA

Comment: I'm just siding with r/cpp on this one where it doesn't matter any more today. People get the idea and your ability to have a technical conversation is not really hampered.  P.S. They edited one of my answers over this technicality.

Comment: Maybe you are just using the wrong algorithm.  std::max_element only loops through once but loops through the nodes so the comparison function has to call Score() on largest every time.  std::accumulate calculates the max element much more like your second loop: `double max = std::accumulate(std::cbegin(nodes), std::cend(nodes), DBL_MIN, [](auto max, Node const& node1) { return std::max(node1.Score(),max); });` and there is probably a way to use std::bind to get rid of the lambda...

Comment: A side effect of `std::cout << "complex calculation\n";` prevents the compiler to optimize the code correctly. It really _must_ call `Score()` every time it is mentioned. Should it be pure, the compiler would cache its results.

Comment: @FredLarson that's from 2008... with the evolution of C++ it's not up to date imho

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacing raw loops with abstracted algorithms is good style because then you can reuse the algorithm many times but test it only once. Wrapping the loop this way may seem like syntactic sugar, but it greatly reduces the potential for bugs in your code because you can now do extensive unit tests on the abstracted algorithm and you never need to worry about mistakenly implementing it incorrectly when you need it.

However, you're comparing apples and oranges here. Your `max_element` implementation always calculates `Score()` for its comparison whereas your `for` loop caches the result of the `Score()` function.

A better implementation of `Node` might be:

```cpp
class Node {
mutable:
    double cached_score = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_Nan();
public:
    auto Score() const -> double {
        if(std::isnan(cached_score)){
           std::cout << "complex calculation\n";
           counter++;
           cached_score = 1;
        }
        return cached_score;
    }
    void invalidate_cache() {
      cached_score = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_Nan();
    }
};
```

This way the complex calculation is only performed once.

Alternatively, write your own abstraction:

```cpp
#include <cfloat>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

static int counter;

class Node {
public:
    auto Score() const -> double {
        std::cout << "complex calculation\n";
        counter++;
        return 1;
    }
};

template<class ForwardIt, class Evaluate, class Compare>
ForwardIt max_eval_element(
    ForwardIt first,
    ForwardIt last,
    Evaluate eval,
    Compare comp
){
    if (first == last) return last;

    ForwardIt largest = first;
    auto largest_val = eval(*first);
    ++first;
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        const auto this_val = eval(*first);
        if (comp(largest_val, this_val)) {
            largest = first;
            largest_val = this_val;
        }
    }
    return largest;
}

int main()
{

    std::array<Node, 10> nodes;

    counter = 0;
    Node const* nodePtr = max_eval_element(std::cbegin(nodes), std::cend(nodes),
                                       [](Node const& node){ return node.Score(); },
                                       [](double const &a, double const &b) {
                                           return a<b;
                                       });
    std::cout << "algorithm count " << counter << std::endl;

    counter = 0;
    double maxScore = -FLT_MAX;
    for (const auto& node : nodes) {
        auto score = node.Score();
        if (score > maxScore) {
            maxScore = score;
            nodePtr = &node;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "raw loop count " << counter << std::endl;
}
```

In this instance, both loops perform the same number of evaluations.

Many internal codebases I've worked with have extensive libraries which extend the STL. It gives the teams I've worked on much greater confidence that their code has been written correctly and allows you to interpret complex operations at a glance. In this way, these abstractions also reduce the effort of understanding code and the effort of communication.

Comment: Shouldn't `Score()` look more like this instead? `auto Score() const -> double { if (std::isnan(cached_score)) { ... cached_score = 1; } return cached_score; }`

Comment: Thank you for both suggestions, but: in the first situation the size of Node grows. So there's again a (memory) performance impact.  And in the second situation you're replacing a raw loop with a new function that effectively has the same raw loop, which just seems optical trickery.

Comment: @JHBonarius: If you're planning on using the `Score()` function repeatedly, then the space-time trade-off is one you'll have to consider anyway.

Comment: @JHBonarius: See the first sentence of my answer. You're replacing a complex inline operation with a call to a generic function which you can write extensive unit tests for. If you use `max_eval_element` twice in a project, this halves the amount of testing you need to do versus the raw loops. It also provides you a function you can move between projects. If you look at the documentation for [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) you'll see that it too is just an abstraction. There's no magic here, only good design practices.

Comment: OK, I'm going for this one. I modified it to `template <typename FwdIt, typename Eval, typename Pred = std::less<>>
constexpr FwdIt max_eval_element(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Eval eval, Pred pred = Pred())`, so I can call it with e.g. `return *max_eval_element(std::begin(nodes), std::end(nodes), std::mem_fn(&Node::Score));` for my code. still need to fix type detection though

Comment: I've just checked the ranges-v3 (C++20 base) implementation of this... The [max_element](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/algorithm/max_element.hpp) offers an extra "projection" input, which could be used to apply a transformation. I.e. `auto nodeIt3 = rng::max_element(nodes, std::less<double>(), [](Node const& node) { return node.Score(); });`, however, the implementation is kind of disappointing: `if(invoke(pred, invoke(proj, *first), invoke(proj, *tmp)))` i.e. the projection is applied twice.

Comment: I've checked this in [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/DKJ71d), and indeed the projection is evaluated twice... quite an inefficient implementation...

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to post the algo I used based on Richard's answer:

```cpp
template <typename FwdIt, typename Proj, typename Comp = std::less<>>
constexpr FwdIt max_projected_element(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Proj proj, Comp comp = {}) {
    auto found = first;
    if (first != last) {
        auto best = std::invoke(proj, *found);
        while (++first != last) {
            if (auto const value = std::invoke(proj, *first);
                std::invoke(comp, best, value)) {
                found = first;
                best = value;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

which allows me to call the algo as

```cpp
Node const* nodePtr = max_projected_element(
    std::cbegin(nodes), std::cend(nodes), &Node::Score);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your case is somewhat pathological to `std::max_element`, since your comparator calls `Score()` on *both* elements every time, and you declare it to be expensive. So where you do:

```
for (const auto& node : nodes) {
    auto score = node.Score();
    if (score > maxScore) {
        maxScore = score;
        nodePtr = &node;
    }
}
```

... `std::max_element` effectively has to do:

```
for (const auto& node : nodes) {
    if (node.Score() > nodePtr->Score()) {
        nodePtr = &node;
    }
}
```

I think `std::max_element` would be just fine in a more normal case, where the value to compare by is cheap to access.

Comment: I disagree with you on "a more normal case". I rarely need to compare just rows of numbers. Usually I need to compare objects, based on the value of a member variable or an evaluation formula. And I think that is is a more common 'normal' case..

Comment: Even for containers of objects, most uses would reference a value that is trivial to access.

Comment: @JHBonarius: Comparison based on "a member variable" access is *very different* from "an evaluation formula". In the former case, `max_element` is just fine; the later case, not so much. Optimizing the latter case requires knowing up-front that the value you're using to compare them is expensive to calculate and therefore should be cached. Which `min_element` cannot know. Essentially, your case is a performance issue because it's really two things: converting a list of some type into a list of values, then comparing based on those values. You optimize this through caching.

Comment: @NicolBolas ... but that is not necessary with a raw loop. So I'd have to introduce a /new/ mechanism to overcome the limitations... that's a high cost just to fulfill this "no raw loops" thing... I think my conclusion is: the current infrastructure is too limited to remove all raw loops. I prefer Richard's solution in that case.

Comment: @JHBonarius: "*but that is not necessary with a raw loop.*" And that's the tradeoff you *always* make for going high-level. The code looks more easily digestible and it's more difficult to make mistakes, but if your high-level needs do not exactly match the expectations of the tools at your disposal (in this case, that comparing values is cheap), then there may be additional overhead compared to a bespoke solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is in how the test is written. The statements

```
    std::cout << "complex calculation\n";
    count++;
```

make a visible side effect, and the compiler is obliged to call `Score` every time it appears. If it was pure (that is, having no side effects), the compiler would optimize the redundant calls away by cacheing.

Try to use a real `Score` (I hope the real one *is* pure), and compare the execution times.

Comment: I tried this. I removed counter and the cout. I added a scoring function that used a lot of `cmath`. Then I increased the node array to 100000 elements and used a `high_resolution_clock` to measure the elapsed time. I compiled with G++ 9.1 with -O3... Result: algorithm uses 22 ms, raw loop uses 8 ms... so I'm afraid this is not true.