# C++ std::mem_fn and std::bind the other way around

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointer-to-member

So I have been looking into using abstracted algorithms to reuse reoccurring patterns in my code. Specifically, I want to determine the the element in an array of nodes that has the highest 'score', determined by evaluation of a complex scoring member function.

After [some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530330/c-no-raw-loops-without-losing-perfomance) I've come up with (C++17)

```
template <typename FwdIt, typename Eval, typename Pred = std::less<>>
constexpr FwdIt max_eval_element(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Eval eval, Pred pred = Pred()) {
    FwdIt found = first;
    if (first != last) {
        auto best = eval(*found);
        while (++first != last) {
            if (auto const thisVal = eval(*first);
                pred(best, thisVal)) {
                found = first;
                best = thisVal;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

So consider my Node class:

```
class Node {
private:
    double val;
public:
    Node(double val) noexcept : val(val) {}

    [[nodiscard]] auto Score1() const noexcept {
        return std::sqrt(std::log(10.0 / val));
    }

    [[nodiscard]] auto Score2(double other) const noexcept {
        return std::sqrt(std::log(other / val));
    }
};
```

and my array of nodes:

```
std::array<Node, 100000> nodes;
```

I can call

```
auto const& Node = *std::max_eval_element(std::cbegin(nodes), std::cend(nodes), std::mem_fn(&Node::Score1));
```

but now I want to repeat this for `Score2`, where the input depends on some local variable... of course I can write some lambda function... but we have `std::bind` for that, right? I know you can cal bind on a member function like

```
std::bind(this, std::mem_fn(Node::Score1));
```

But what I want is the other way around. Which doesn't work.

```
auto const& Node = *std::max_eval_element(std::cbegin(nodes), std::cend(nodes), std::bind(std::mem_fn(&Node::Score2), 1.0));
```

I tried it the other way around, but that also doesn't work

```
auto const& Node = *std::max_eval_element(std::cbegin(nodes), std::cend(nodes), std::mem_fn(std::bind(&Node::Score2), 1.0));
```

I know *why* this doesn't work... a member function requires the object pointer as a (hidden) first argument. But that would mean we are missing something like `std::bind_mem_fn` or so... We had `std::bind2nd` in the past, but it has been removed in C++17...

Again: of course I can use a lambda, but considering things like `std:mem_fn` and `std::bind` exist, and abstracted algorithms is a good thing...

Am I missing something, Or is this just missing from the standard?

Comment: "I can write some lambda function... but we have std::bind for that, right?" -> that's the other way around; you should really prefer lambda's because they raise a lot less questions than using `std::bind` does.

Comment: @rubenvb I think opinions differ on that... also: DRY... if all lambda's look the same, abstraction would be preferred (opinionated)

Comment: nothing prevents you from not repeating yourself with lambda's. You don't have to declare them inline for starters.

Comment: and lambdas tend to be optimized much better by the compilers...

Comment: @bartop do they? better then memfn and bind? you have proof?

Comment: Isn't this what `std::placeholders` is for? `std::bind(std::mem_fn(&Node::Score2), std::placeholders::_1, 1.0)` https://godbolt.org/z/v_U40a

Comment: Also, your `max_eval_element` does not handle empty ranges properly. The `auto best = eval(*found);` should be in the `if`.

Comment: AFAIK "Effective Modern C++" by Scott Meyers

Comment: @JHBonarius using lambdas does not necessarily imply to violate DRY. You can eg write a function that returns the lambda and reuse it whereever you like.

Comment: The bind expression is much less readable.

Comment: @JHBonarius both lambdas and bind are prvalue expressions of some object type you don't want to (or can't) name. There is no difference in DRYness between their use

Comment: @bartop , hmm maybe you're right there... I tried some code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zDr5CS). If you look at the lambda version, it seemed the division was inlined, while the mem_fn results in a function call... weird... I wouldn't expect this. Thanks for the insight

Comment: Lambdas are way more flexible and idiomatic than `std::bind`. They amount to (more or less) syntactic sugar for functor objects, so the compiler is guaranteed to have all the information it could use for optimization right at its fingertips. `std::bind` comes from a time before lamdbas existed and has been superseded by them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call `std::bind(&Node::Score2)` is the problem. It lacks arguments to pass to `Score2`. You want:

```
std::bind(&Node::Score2, std::placeholders::_1, 1.0)
```

This is not a pointer-to-member, so it is not an appropriate argument to `std::mem_fn`

Alternatively, you can use a lambda

```
[](const auto & node) { return node.Score2(1.0); }
```

Comment: Noice! So `std::mem_fn(&someFn)` is effectively equal to `std::bind(&someFn, std::placeholders::_1)`?

Comment: haha, true... is not equal then... It would be an accident waiting to happen

Comment: infact, no, it's akin to `std::bind(&SomeClass::someFn, std::placeholders::_1, ... std::placeholders::_N)`, i.e. it always has exactly the right number of parameters

Answer (score 0):

I've come to the conclusion that lambda's optimize better than std::mem_fn

Take this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <functional>

class Node {
private:
    double val;
public:
    Node(double val) noexcept : val(val) {}

    [[nodiscard]] auto Score() const noexcept {
        return 10.0 / val;
    }
};

template <typename FwdIt, typename Eval, typename Pred = std::less<>>
constexpr FwdIt max_eval_element(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Eval eval, Pred pred = Pred()) {
    FwdIt found = first;
    if (first != last) {
        auto best = eval(*found);
        while (++first != last) {
            if (auto const thisVal = eval(*first);
                pred(best, thisVal)) {
                found = first;
                best = thisVal;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<Node, 10> nodes{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    auto nodeIt1 = max_eval_element(std::cbegin(nodes), std::cend(nodes), std::mem_fn(&Node::Score));
    std::cout << "dist1 " << std::distance(std::cbegin(nodes), nodeIt1) << std::endl;

    auto nodeIt2 = max_eval_element(std::cbegin(nodes), std::cend(nodes), [](Node const& node) { return node.Score(); });
    std::cout << "dist2 " << std::distance(std::cbegin(nodes), nodeIt2) << std::endl;
}
```

If you look at the compiled assembly (e.g. [on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fDiu1Q), with -O2 ), the std:mem_fn results is a function call

```
42 movsd   QWORD PTR [rsp+8], xmm1
43 call    Node::Score() const
44 movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
```

, while the lambda is inlined

```
69 movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
70 divsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rax]
```

Comment: No surprise. `mem_fn` invocations go through a function pointer, which are notoriously difficult to optimize away. Lambdas use a direct function call, which are a piece of cake for any garden-variety optimizer.

Comment: Bah... apparently insight and explanation thereof is good enough to get you a -1 on stack overflow. Whatever happened to "be nice"?